# Writing information at the end of a file in C

Tags: c, file, io

I want to write some information to the end of a existing file in C. Here is my sample code:

```
foo2(some parameter)
{
   id++
   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    { 
      dumpfile(i)
    }
}

dumpfile(int i)
{
   f = fopen(filename,"a");
  fprintf(f,"hello : %d\n",i);

}
```

Output:
hello : 9
hello : 8
........
.....
hello : 0

But I want:
hello : 0
hello : 1
.......
...
hello : 9

The problem is when I open the file after the execution, I see that the latest information is wrote at the top of the file and not at the end of the file. It is supposed to write at the end of the file. How can I open a file at append mode in a loop and write information at the end of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By opening the file in append mode (`"a"`) you are placed at the end of the file.

However the error in your code, is that you are not closing the file between open calls.

```
f = fopen(filename, "a");
fprintf(f, "hello: %d\n", i);
fclose(f);
```

If you want to be also to write anywhere in the file, you should open it `"r+"` and then you can use `fseek()` to move to any position. Such as going to the end of the file:

```
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
```

However the file must already exist.

As a personal preference I prefer to use `open()` and friends over the file ones.

Comment: Thanks man! I was missing the the fclose part. Thats why information was written at the beginning.

Comment: Seeking is not possible if the file is opened in "append" mode. Closing the file, however, is important. Good catch.

Comment: @MOehm you are correct! I just read the `fopen()` man page again. So @Luniam's issue was just never closing the file. BTW, it'd be more effective to not open/close the file between calls (in this simple example).

Comment: @TimothyBrown: I was surprised to learn that, too. (I also checked the man page before commenting.)

Comment: @Luniam yes, open it as `"r+"` and use `fseek()`. But watch out as `fseek()` takes the offset as bytes.

Comment: Sorry, if it is naive. while opening file using fopen in r+ what should I use for writing to the file? fprintf? I used that and nothing is written in the file.

Comment: CODE:....................................................for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
     if(i==8)
     {
      f = fopen(cycleInfoFileName11,"r+");
      fseek(f,4,SEEK_END);
      fprintf(f,"holla................!!!");
      fclose(f);
      //break;
     }
     else{
      f = fopen(cycleInfoFileName11,"a");

      fprintf(f,"</component>\n");
      fprintf(f,"hello %d\n",i);
      fprintf(f,"</component>\n");
      fclose(f);
     }
    }

Comment: @Luniam Your `fseek()` here has SEEK_END with an offset, so you will create a hole in your file.